# How can I compute the mean autocorrelation if the autocorrelation coefficient is a matrix?

Tags: statistics

Usually, the lag-1 autocorrelation is given by $$y_{n+1} = \alpha y_{n} + \epsilon_n + c$$  Here, $a,y_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$.  The expectation of this process is

$$\mu = \dfrac{c}{1 - \alpha}$$

Suppose that $y_n \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $a \in M^{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$.  How can I compute the mean autocorrelation now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms used in the question is not accurate and here is my interpretation. You have demonstrate how to express the mean of a autoregressive model of order $1$ ($AR(1)$ model) in terms of the given parameters. Here we should have assumed that the process/time series has the same mean throughout the all $n$ (or a stronger assumption of statationarity). And of course the error term has mean zero.

Now you try to extend it to the vector case, so you are essentially dealing with a $VAR(1)$, vector autoregressive model. So $y_n, \epsilon_n, c, \mu \in \mathbb{R}^N$ are all vectors and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ is a matrix now. We still have the following representation of the model, but now it is a matrix equation:

$$ y_{n+1} = \alpha y_n + \epsilon_n + c $$

Taking expectation on both sides,
$$  \begin{align} && \mu &= \alpha \mu + 0 + c \\
\Rightarrow && (I - \alpha)\mu &= c \\
\Rightarrow && \mu & = (I-\alpha)^{-1}c
\end{align}$$

where $I \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ is the identity matrix, and we have assumed that $I - \alpha$ is invertible.